# When I create a new userspace thead, it will appear on kernel process list?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I write a program name test.c. In this program, I created three thread by pthead_create. These thread named thread0, thread1, thread2 by prctl(PR_SET_NAME, name). The thread function code as follows:

```
    void *output(void *arg) {

            char *x = (char *) arg;
            char name[40] = "thread";
            strcat(name, x);
            prctl(PR_SET_NAME, name);
            while(1){
                    printf("%s\n", name);
                    sleep(10000);
            };
    }
```

Then I write a kernel module print.c which function is to print the each task_struct infomation int kernel process list. the code as follows:

```
    struct task_struct *task = &init_task;

    do{
            printk("%s\n", task->comm);
    }while((task=next_task(task)) != &init_task);
```

I run the program test.c first correctly and then insmod the module print.ko correctly. Unexpectly, I didn't find three threads' information. So, I want to ask that the thread created by pthread_create would not appear on kernel process list. is this opinion  correct or not?

Comment: Why would you expect the threads to appear in the process list?

Comment: @StoryTeller Because, on Linux, user-space threads are kernel processes. This is a relic of history (from before the kernel distinguished between processes and kernel scheduling entities), but it is what it is and we have to live with it.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - I know they were in the obsolete LinuxThreads implementation of pthreads. Is it still the case today?

Comment: I just want to know if it will appear in the process list.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - User space constructs? With different process ID's? Yeah, I see why it was scrapped.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - According to http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html they did have a separate process ID. So color me confused. I admit to never actually *using* LinuxThreads however.

Comment: Sorry, I'm remembering the history incorrectly. LinuxThreads was the first implementation that used the kernel to schedule threads, even though the kernel called them processes. (Because, for historical reasons, the kernel called everything it scheduled a process.) This is largely still the case. For example, the Linux kernel's "process table" has an entry for everything it schedules, which includes every thread.

Answer (score 0):

A thread is also represented by a `struct task` in the kernel. You can iterate through each thread in a task by using e.g. the  [while_each_thread](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/sched.h#L3057) macro:

```
struct task_struct *task = ...;
struct task_struct *t = task;
do {
    //use t
} while_each_thread(task, t);
```

Note: I don't know the proper locking, if any, around the task structs you need to be able to iterate through them like this.